# POST from Typescript to Web API API, unable to pass a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to pass a JSON Object from a typescript POST call to a Web API method. 
Fiddler shows that the object has been converted into JSON and the Content-Type is 'application/JSON'. But at the API controller, the parameter value displays null instead of JSON.

Typescript:

```
createPO(product: string): Promise<string> {
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   return this._http.post(this._creatPOUrl, JSON.stringify(product), options)
   .toPromise()
   .then(response => <string>response.statusText)
   .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

Web API: 
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task CreatePOInMO([FromBody] string product)
        {
        return Ok();
        }

product contains null. 
If I pass the actual value inside product object from typescript(which is a JSON) , it works. But I cannot hard code like this.

I followed this post : [Angular2 Service not passing JSON to WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574468/angular2-service-not-passing-json-to-webapi)
But it looks like I am doing whatever is mentioned here.

Comment: Can you post your WEB-API configuration ? I suppose the JSON converter does not expect the JSON format in the same way as the standard JSON for example I had a similar problem posting { name: 'test' } from front end ant the expected class in the be was { Name: 'test' } because of the camel case the WEB-API standard converter could not translate the response. also a request could be helpful

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 2, when [posting JSON with the Http client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update), you should not call `JSON.stringify`:

```
this._http.post(this._creatPOUrl, product, options)
```

Comment: Changed it to :
var POCartItems = JSON.stringify(product);
return this._http.post(this._creatPOUrl, POCartItems , options)

and at Web API: [HttpPost]public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreatePOInMO([FromBody] string POCartItems)
Still not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `JSON.stringify` call is not required. Have a look at the linked documentation/guide.